# E-Commerce website in salesforce in developer org

Tags: force.com-sites, licenses, e-commerce

Hi I want to start with my small ecommerce website.
I am going to use developer org. As my cost for development is low.

I know the limitation of salesforce like size, object limitations etc..
This limitations are fine with me.

What all other constraints should I consider and what should I refer. 
Can you suggest me weather I should go with salesforce or should I look for other technologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salesforce DE's are free to help Devs learn to develop on the platform and Devs agree to the TOS when they sign up for them. Commercial use would be a violation of those Terms of Service (TOS).

There are also limits on the number of visits to a site in a 24 hour period. This kind of use would be violating the spirit of why Salesforce provides an unlimited number of DE's to us that are totally free.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to purchase an org atleast with one license .Its illegal to use developer organization for your commercial purpose .

You may be in serious legal issues .Talk to salesforce on this and you may need a simple license .

With other technology the go to market speed is less and development time and maintainence can be huge deal .